# Can you use 2 async functions at the same time when working with 2 .json files? (Two different .json text files)

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, request

If not then how can you work with 2 .json files at the same time? It does't seem to work so if there exists another method I should try and use that. If you could provide the correct syntax to achieve the goal it would be appreciated. Does the second .json file ever get processed?

```
sync function populate() {

    const requestURL = 'nascar.json';
    const request = new Request(requestURL);
    
    const response = await fetch(request);
    const nascarDrivers = await response.json();
    
    findDriver(nascarDrivers);
}

async function texas() {

    const requestURL = 'texasMS.json';
    const request = new Request(requestURL);
    
    const response = await fetch(request);
    const texasLaps = await response.json();
    
    findLaps(texasLaps);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you run them one by one, without `await`ing them, they will run in parallel (sort-of).

```js
populate()
texas()
```

If you want to wait for the results as they come back, you can use `Promise.all`:

```js
const promises = [
  populate(),
  texas(),
]
Promise.all(promises).then((results) => {
  const [populateRes, texasRes] = results
  // ...
})
// or
const results = await Promise.all(promises)
```